# URL with multiple parameters throws a NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I aim to redirect the view after the form has been saved. However django keeps throwing a NoReverseMatch error. Is there a step that I've missed or a misconfiguration?
**views.py**

```
def add_carpet(request):
context_dict = {}
carpet_form = forms.CarpetForm()

if request.method == "POST":
    carpet_form = forms.CarpetForm(request.POST)

    if carpet_form.is_valid():
        carpet = carpet_form.save()

        return redirect(reverse(
            "dashboard_add_images",
            kwargs={
                "model_type": "carpet",
                "id": carpet.id
            }
        ))


context_dict["carpet_form"] = carpet_form

return render(
    request,
    'dashboard/add_carpet.html',
    context_dict
)
def add_images(request, model_type, id):
  ...
```

**add_images.hml**

```
{% extends 'layouts/dashboard_base.html' %}
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Add Images{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col justify-content-end">
           <h1 class="heading half_space text-muted">
               Add Images for the {model}
               <span class="divider-left"></span>
           </h1>
      </div>
   </div>

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}

{# Display a form #}
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'dashboard_add_images' %}" method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}

    
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

    {% bootstrap_button button_type="submit" content="OK" %}

</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

From above you can see I added the enctype on the form but still no change.
**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('add_carpet', views.add_carpet, name="dashboard_add_carpet"),
path('add_images/<str:model_type>/<uuid:id>', views.add_images, name="dashboard_add_images"),]
```

An example redirect url after a form has been submitted is this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/add_images/carpet/97afd259-6ec4-48fc-869f-2a00bbe29c70
```

Error:

```
Reverse for 'dashboard_add_images' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/add_images/(?P<model_type>[^/]+)/(?P<id>[^/]+)$']
```

Comment: Can you share the template you are rendering in `add_images`...

Comment: Sorry, hadn't seen your comment.